# CSS jqzoom align problems

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

Hi I have setup a gallery where images are listed in thumbnails alongside the main image which can in turn be zoomed by the user.

However, for some reason, when I use 3 thumbnails (4 align perfectly with the main image), instead of listing them from the top of the div, they are aligned from the bottom so the webpage looks like:

```
   ________
   |       |
 _ |       |
|_||       |
 _ |       |
|_||       |
 _ |       |
|_||_______|
```

instead of

```
 _ ________
|_||       |
 _ |       |
|_||       |
 _ |       |
|_||       |
   |       |
   |_______|
```

My css is:

```
.clearfix:after{clear:both;content:".";display:block;font-size:0;height:0;line-height:0;visibility:hidden;}
.clearfix{display:block;zoom:1}


ul#thumblist{display:block; margin-left:-40px;}
ul#thumblist li{float:left;margin-right:6px; margin-bottom:4px; margin-top:-2px;list-style:none;}
ul#thumblist li a{display:block;border:1px solid #666}
ul#thumblist li a.zoomThumbActive{
   border:1px solid #F7941E;

}
```

and my html is:

```
<table border>
  <tr>
    <td width="101" rowspan="4"><div class="clearfix" >
    <ul id="thumblist" class="clearfix" >
        <li><a class="zoomThumbActive" href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './imgProd/1.jpg',largeimage: './imgProd/1.jpg'}"><img src='imgProd/1.jpg' style="width:110px; height:110px;"></a></li>
        <li><a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './imgProd/2.jpg',largeimage: './imgProd/2.jpg'}"><img src='imgProd/2.jpg' style="width:110px; height:110px;"></a></li>
        <li><a  href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './imgProd/3.jpg',largeimage: './imgProd/3.jpg'}"><img src='imgProd/3.jpg' style="width:110px; height:110px;"></a></li>
    <li><a  href='javascript:void(0);' rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './imgProd/4.jpg',largeimage: './imgProd/4.jpg'}"><img src='imgProd/4.jpg' style="width:110px; height:110px;"></a></li>

    </ul>
    </div></td>
    <td width="450" rowspan="4"><div class="clearfix">
        <a href="imgProd/1.jpg" class="jqzoom" rel='gal1'  title="" >
            <img src="imgProd/1.jpg"  title=""   style="border:2px solid #F7941E;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); width:450px; height:450px;">
        </a>

</div></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Why wont the images align vertically from the top of the div/table as opposed to aligning from the bottom? Any help much appreciated!!

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use

```
tr{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7fp8s/